# Is Android development possible on netbooks?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I would like to use my netbook for Android development, but when I try to run the SDK with Eclipse, nothing loads. Are netbooks generally powerful enough for Android development? Why or why not?

Comment: I don't think this needs to be migrated, because it _is_ programming-related. The original question gave specific hardware details, which would make it too localized if anything. Rather than flag it as too localized, I've edited them out, per [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/). (And, for that matter, tried to make it "Good Subjective," per [this one](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).)

Comment: depends on your "netbook", you can have quite decent netbooks w/ an external screen/keyboard/mouse as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to see where the line for a netbook is drawn, but i'm do develop on my "netbook", but it does have 3Gig mem, and a dual core proc, so the only netbookish about it, is that it's a small, 12" thing.

The small screen is a bit of a problem sometimes, as a bigger-screen emulator sometimes doesn't really fit.

I'd not readily use something with even less memory, as eclipse, a VM and ofcourse various things like browsers and all, are a bit heavy on the mem.

Concuding: yes, you can develop on a netbook if you stretch the definition a bit. I'd not choose a low-end netbook, choose one with enough mem and you should be aware that a small screen is a limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Possible?  Yes.

Fun?  No.

Worthwhile?  When making any degree of progress right now is preferable until waiting until you are in front of a better machine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, perhaps not what's really meant, [but here's a link to a web based app creator for Android.](http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/)

But I whine enough about having to develop on my "measly" 4 gig mem laptop.

YMMV

Answer (score 0):

I develop on my MSI Wind U100 (with an 1gb of ram) every now and again, and it's perfectly fine for it.

(10" screen 1024x600)

Although I use Eclipse, I don't use the emu.