# Running the Android SDK on ARM-netbook (Ubuntu)

Tags: android, sdk, arm

I'm trying to install an Android developement environment (JDK+SDK+Eclipse+Plugins) on my Toshiba AC100 (ARM architecture), but

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

says the SDK is only available for x86 architecture. Does anyone have an idea how to get it running on my device? I'm using Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4930775/1101070) doesn't address your ARM question, but it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: I'm trying to run the SDK on an Android ARM device itself, and I hit this same problem.

Answer (score 0):

based on TerminalIDE chrooted arm env for compilling APK on android devices,

there is maybe a way to isolate compiller binaries to run under linux-arm

I'll try, if I'm able, I will let you known ....

But you will have notepad/eclipse // cmd line compillation (you could make an ant env or some not ugly .sh)

Answer (score 0):

ok, a bit more ....

(based on terminal ide env & w32 env)

You'll need jdk (arm) then

- aapt (is a binary so needs to find its sources ;( but it's just required to create R.java (resource id manager) -- if you project to make a cli program : it is not mandatory...)  | ;( |
- dx is a JVM script : that calls a pure java jar (w32 uses **dx.jar** from sdk) | ;) |
- apkbuilder is a JVM script : that calls a pure java jar (w32 uses **sdklib.jar** from sdk) | ;) |
- javac is the classical javac but add **android.jar** to its classpath (I recommend the API-8 froyo version to be most compatible) | ;) |